# Ускорение работы Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Как можно ускорить загрузку и работу Eclipse без подтормаживания? У меня вроде ноут не слабый, 6GB памяти, я слышал можно как-то установить количество используемой ОЗУ, подскажите.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В папке где лежит Eclipse есть файлик eclipse.ini, кури его.
Вот небольшая помощь [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё скачать специальный плагин. Help>marketplace. Там будет плагин в самом начале, ещё ракета нарисована.